# Easy way to implement anonymous metafunctions (Lambdas)

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, lambda

I'm working on a string manipulation library using template metaprogramming. I use C++11 generalized constant expressions [like in this article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2012/10/using-strings-in-c-template-metaprograms/) to access raw-strings elements at compile time, generating a typelist which holds the characters, a type the metaprogramming library can deal with:

```
template<typename INDEX>
struct transform_function
{
    using result = tml::character<"hello world!"[INDEX::value]>;
};

//tml::for_each returns the set of applications of each element of the specified
//interval on the specified metafunction. In other words, generates a typelist
//which contains each character of the string:

using str = tml::for_each<tml::make_size_t_forward_iterator<0> , 
                          tml::make_size_t_forward_iterator<sizeof("hello world!")> ,
                          transform_function>;

using hello2 = tml::concat<str,str>; //hello2 holds "hello world!hello world!"
```

I have written a macro which generates the code above from an specified raw string and names it with an specified name. For example:

```
TURBO_STRING_VARIABLE( hello , "hello " );
TURBO_STRING_VARIABLE( world , "world!" );

using hello_world = tml::concat<hello,world>;
```

Now what I want is a macro like this to generate annonimous strings, that is, something like this:

```
template<typename STRING>
struct to_upper{ ... };

using HELLO_WORLD = typename to_upper<hello_world>::result; //OK, holds "HELLO WORLD!"
using HELLO = typename to_upper<ANONYMOUS_STRING("hello")>; //HELLO
```

My `for_each` approach doesn't work because I cannot define a type in the context of a template argumment pass, but I was thinking in a kind of lambda metafunction to write the transform function directly into the argumment.
I know that Boost.MPL has something like this which uses placeholders, but I think that cannot be used in this context, because I'm using the parameter in a context that has nothing to do with a template (The index operator of the array) and the placeholder trick cannot be applied.

**Is there any other approach to achieve this?**

Comment: It is described in the article. They are able to write f<_S("Hello World!")>.

Comment: @JanHerrmann yeap, but they are able to do that because they are using fixed length typelists to store the strings. I want typelists with the lenght of the string. However, this needs to compute the length of the string (with `sizeof`), and traverse it transforming the indices into characters. What I need is to write that transform function inside the template parameter itselft, that is, a lambda metafunction.

Answer (score 1):

In the article is a way described to implement `ANONYMOUS_STRING` with a maximum length of strings. This should be in general no problem. Simply take 100 as a maximum and assert when strings are longer. Users can create longer strings by concatenation of shorter strings. With 100 chars you usualy have very long lines and need to break them anyway (think about readability of source code in terminal windows).

```
concat<
  ANONYMOUS_STRING("Hello "),
  ANONYMOUS_STRING("World "),
  ANONYMOUS_STRING("!")
>
```

With this code it is possible to produce longer strings in a readable manner.

The general problem is string literals can not be template arguments and you can not create an class inside at the point you think of:

```
template<class T>
struct f{};

using g=f<struct { /* some types and data */ }>; // does not work
```

The way is to instanciate another template at the point:

```
using g=f<std::integral_constant<char, 'x'>>; // does work
```

So I think you have to create a macro which is to big for small strings and to small for big strings. This is the way Abel Sinkovics and Dave Abrahams have described it. A nice effect is you can replace `TURBO_STRING_VARIABLE( hello , "hello " );` with a far better `using hello = ANONYMOUS_STRING("hello");`